# How to send data of radio buttons/radio group using volley when checked

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-volley

I am doing a register form for an app I'm creating. It includes first name, last name, email, phone number, password, birth day and gender. The gender in a radio group, obviously using radio buttons. I am using Volley for networking data. How do I pass the checked radio button value using volley?

Here is my java code **so far**:

```
public class B_Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://10.0.0.245/register_alex's_app.php";

public static final String FNAME_REGISTER = "first_name";
public static final String LNAME_REGISTER = "last_name";
public static final String EMAIL_REGISTER = "email_register";
public static final String USERNAME_REGISTER = "username_register";
public static final String PHONE_NUMBER_REGISTER = "phone_register";
public static final String PASSWORD_REGISTER = "password_register";
public static final String BDAY_REGISTER = "bday_register";


private EditText fname;
private EditText lname;
private EditText email;
private EditText phone_number;
private EditText new_username;
private EditText new_password;
private EditText bday;

private RadioGroup gender;

private Button register_btn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b_register);

    fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name_et);
    lname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.last_name_et);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_et);
    phone_number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone_et);
    new_username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_et);
    new_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_et);
    bday = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bday_et);

    gender = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.gender_register);

    register_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
    register_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onTermsOfUseClick(View view) {
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    final String firstName = fname.getText().toString().trim();
    final String lastName = lname.getText().toString().trim();
    final String new_email = email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String newPhoneNumber = phone_number.getText().toString().trim();
    final String userName = new_username.getText().toString().trim();
    final String newPassword = new_password.getText().toString().trim();
    final String bDay = bday.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName)) {
        fname.setError("Please enter your first name.");
        return;
    }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName)) {
        lname.setError("Please enter your last name.");
        return;
    }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(new_email)) {
        email.setError("Please enter your email.");
        return;
    }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newPhoneNumber)) {
        phone_number.setError("Please enter your phone number.");
        return;
    }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
        new_username.setError("Please enter a valid username, 5-25 characters.");
        return;
    }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newPassword)) {
        new_password.setError("Please enter valid password, 5-15 characters.");
    }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(bDay)) {
        bday.setError("Please enter your birth day.");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To know the selected `RadioButton` id check:

```
 // get selected radio button from radioGroup
 int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 // find the radiobutton by returned id
 radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
 String radio_value = radioButton.getText(); //by this you will get the male or female text which will be used in sending to server.
```

To send the data using `Volley`, add dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Volley method to send data to server:

```
                try {
                // initialize request to connect the server, via POST method and Server URl
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, your_url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            // catch JSON response from server
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(final String response) {
                                // response from server
                            }
                        },

                        // catch error response from server
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(final VolleyError error) {
                                // trace error message from server 
                            }
                        }){

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // map the string value, to send in server
                        params.put("name",string_value_of_name);
                        params.put("sex",string_value_of_sex);
                        .... //like more
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                // execute the request
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(your_activity_context.this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            }catch (final Exception e){
                //catch exception
            }
```

Must visit link for more details [Here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/)

Note: This example is just for demonstration purpose and does not contains exact answer asked by user, must apply your idea using shown process/logic.

Answer (score 0):

access the radio button directly, instead of the radiogroup.

```
RadioButton male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male);
boolean isMale = male.isChecked();
```

remember to label your radiobuttons.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/gender_register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_male"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_female" />

</RadioGroup>
```